# Install spotify on raspberry pi 3 and run it remotely

Tags: audio-playback

I try mopidy and runeaudio, but the interfaces seem odd to me.

I want to install the Spotify app on my Raspberry 3, and access music through a URL I can share with anyone connected to my wifi. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least part of what you want to do is possible. Here's a link to a [repo on GitHub containing some instructions for installing `raspotify`](https://github.com/dtcooper/raspotify), and downloads to get this running.

When you say, "access music through a URL I can share with anyone connected to my wifi"... First, I'm unclear on what exactly you want to do - perhaps you could edit your question to explain that more clearly. Second, just guessing at your objectives, I'm not sure you can do that, or that you should do that. Please review Spotify's licensing terms, and make sure you're in compliance.

Hope that helps.